# force android to resize text like iphone when phone rotated

Tags: android, css, ios

i see plenty of requests asking how to stop the iphone from resizing text when the phones are rotated into landscape mode, i want this to happen on android phones however like it does on the iphone.  Everything i research points me to turning off the feature on iphones using -webkit-text-size-adjust: none;

is there somehow something in css that will force the android browser to infact resize this text when the device is rotated like the iphone does ?

Comment: By getting the screen orientation you can change the size of the text as you want

Comment: You mean on landscape mode you need text to be viewed bigger than its showing in portrait view. Just make 2 new layout folders "layout-pot" & "layout-land" in "res" and set the changes in layout.xml, its just a type of thing which you can do, not sure with webkit.

Answer (score 1):

Media queries are great for this kind of thing. What I've seen most is `min-width` and `max-width` but you can also use `orientation` as a flag, as noted here: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/how-to-use-css3-orientation-media-queries/

```
/* Portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* Portrait styles */
}
/* Landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* Landscape styles */
}
```

This would allow you to specify a different font size for both the portrait and landscape view of your website.